# In C# how to stop/start/check whether registered or not if the Log On As account is of non-admin user?

Tags: c#, service

I have a service whose LogOnAs is not Local System.It is a different user (say test with administrative privilege).Using Normal  code :doesnt work it always throws exception.

```
 public  bool IsServiceInstalled(String serviceName)
    {
        bool IsInstalled = false;
        // get list of Windows services
        ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

        // try to find service name
        foreach (ServiceController service in services)
        {
            if (service.ServiceName == serviceName)
            {
                IsInstalled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return IsInstalled;
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you can simplify your logic with:

```
public  bool IsServiceInstalled(String aServiceName)
{
   ServiceController sc = ServiceController.GetServices()
       .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == aServiceName);

   return (sc != null) ;
}
```

This uses linq to get the first matching service with the passed name (I've changed the parameter to `aServiceName`, the `a` stands for argument).

It won't solve your problem, but will be easier to read and maintain.

Does this work for you when you're logged on normally?

Comment: Its actually Working for me when i am logged in normally...as i am only interested whether its registered or not...so it solves my problem.. Thanks a lot...